# Proof of every PID is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, noetherian

I saw the proof of this proposition in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271399/proof-that-every-principal-ideal-domain-is-noetherian?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I have a question about this.

Definition of Noetherian ring is that ring is commutative, and every ideal of R is finitely generated, right? Principal ring is that ring's every ideal generated by single element, so it is clear. But I curious about isn't that not only PID, but also Principal ring is Noetherian?

Thank you!

Comment: In the question you have linked, the proof by OP is not correct, as pointed out in the comments. Check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409466/every-principal-ideal-domain-satisfies-accp) which is hyperlinked as the original in your link, since the linked one has been marked duplicate.

Comment: What is a principal ring?

Comment: Our professor says, A commutative ring R is called a principal ring(principal ideal ring) if every ideal of R is principal (i.e., every ideal R is generated by a single element).

Comment: Principal ring is just generated by a single element which is also commutative, so we can say it is also Noetherian. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it has nothing to do with being a domain.

In a principal ideal ring, all ideals are finitely generated because *a fortiori* they are *singly* generated. That is, a one-element generating set is a finite generating set!

The thing is that in some contexts authors are just sticking to domains.   So there is no big mystery about including the domain condition, it's just a context thing.